# How can I fetch metadata for all audio files from a specific folder on my SD Card using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-track-player

I am working on an audio playing app using React Native, but I'm having trouble fetching files using a file/folder picker. Basically, I have audio files saved in a certain folder on my device (not in the project directory). I want to fetch files using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker or folders using react-native-directory-picker (or something like these), and fetch the metadata including uri, to react-native-track-player, but the url fetched by the file picker doesn't seem to work with the track player. Is there a better way to go about this?

Here's the implementation I've tried so far. Note, I have the file saved under the Downloads folder on my local device, and I've tried passing str, str2, str3, and str4. Each time, I get the error logged from reac-native-sound: 'failed to load the sound':

```
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
var Sound = require('react-native-sound');
Sound.setCategory('Playback');
      
async SingleFilePicker() {
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.audio],
      });

      this.setState({audioFile: res});
      Alert.alert('You picked ' + res.name + ' with uri: ' + res.uri);
      // Create audio object with name, artist, album, and length
      // Display object
      var str = 'content://';
      var str2 = res.uri;
      var str3 = str2.split('//').pop();
      console.log(str3);
      var str4 = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Downloads/signofthecross_22_gaume_128kb.mp3';
      var whoosh = new Sound(str4, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('failed to load the sound ' + str4, error);
          return;
        }
        // loaded successfully
        console.log(
          'duration in seconds: ' +
            whoosh.getDuration() +
            'number of channels: ' +
            whoosh.getNumberOfChannels(),
        );

        // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
        whoosh.play((success) => {
          if (success) {
            console.log('successfully finished playing');
          } else {
            console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        Alert.alert('Canceled Operations');
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you tried implement with RNTrackPlayer yet? if yes, please provide code and the error which you mean 'doesn't seem to work with the track player'

Comment: @QuangThái thanks, I just updated my post to include that.